# Injectivity radius and universal cover of a riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces

Suppose that $\tilde M$ is the universal cover of a complete riemannian manifold $M$. I was reading a book and the author said to remember that if we consider the covering projection $p:\tilde M\rightarrow M$ and $r$ the injectivity radius of $M$. Then $d(x,y)< r$ implies that $d(p(x),p(y))=d(x,y)$.

Does anyone know a reference where I can look this up ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you assume that $M$ is complete?

Comment: Yes I am assuming that

Comment: The proof is quite simple: Hint: think of minimizing geodesic $\gamma$ joining $x, y$, then $p(\gamma)$ joins $p(x)$, $p(y)$. Now use the definition of injectivity radius.